# Trivial norm on algebraic filed extention

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K/k$ - algebraic extension and $||.||$ - norm on it, such that limitation of this norm to $k$ - is trivial ($||x||=1$, if $x\neq 0$, and $||x||=0$, if $x=0$). Prove that $||.||$ - is trivial.

My attempt:
Let's prove it for simple extension with primitive element $\alpha$ and minimal polynom $a_n\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+...+a_0=0$. From the last equality we can conclude that $||a_n\alpha^n+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}+..||=||-a_0||=1$ or $$||\alpha||||a_n\alpha^{n-1}+...+a_1|||=1$$. From this we can derive that $$||\alpha||\leq 1$$.

But then we need to show that $$||\alpha||=1$$ and $$||a\alpha+b||=1$$. How to do it?

Comment: instead of supposing that $K$ is generated by $\alpha$, simply take any $0\neq\alpha\in K$; what you did then proves what you want

Comment: @user8268 thanks, but I need to prove then the implication $||\alpha||\leq1 \Rightarrow ||\alpha||=1$. How to do it?

Comment: replace $\alpha$ by $1/\alpha$

Comment: @user8268 Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you meant a ring norm ie. $\|b\|>0$ for $b\in K^*$, $\|b+c\|\le \|b\|+\|c\|,\|bc\|\le \|b\|\|c\|$ then it is not true, try with $\|0\|=0,\|b\|=1$ if $b\in \Bbb{R}^*$, $\|b\|=2$ if $b\in \Bbb{C}-\Bbb{R}$.

If you meant an absolute value ie. $\|bc\|= \|b\|\|c\|$ then assume that $b\in K^*$ is such that $\|b\|\ne 1$, take $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $\|b^m\|=\|b\|^m< \frac1{[k(b):k]}$.

Let $\sum_{d=0}^{[k(b^m):k]} a_d x^d\in k[x]$ be $b^m$'s minimal polynomial. You'll have $$1=\|a_0\|=\|\sum_{d=1}^{[k(b^m):k]} a_d b^{md}\|\le \sum_{d=1}^{[k(b^m):k]} \|a_d\|\| b^m\|^d < 1$$ a contradiction.